# Isolate values in string which are separated by commas or spaces and may also be wrapped in double quotes

Tags: php, arrays, regex, preg-match-all, text-extraction

I'm trying to `preg_split()` a string of tags delimited by commas, double quotes, or spaces.

This is the code I have so far. The idea is to make it as easy as possible for the user to input tags without the use of a javascript solution (which I may go to later).

```
$tagfield = 'Tag Tag2, Tag3 "Tag" "A Tag"';

$tags = preg_split('/[^(.)^a-zA-Z0-9]+/', $tagfield, NULL, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

The output I'm getting is:

```
array (
    0 => 'Tag',
    1 => 'Tag2',
    2 => 'Tag3',
    3 => 'Tag',
    4 => 'A',
    5 => 'Tag',
)
```

My desired output would be:

```
array (
    0 => 'Tag',
    1 => 'Tag2',
    2 => 'Tag3',
    3 => 'Tag',
    4 => 'A Tag',
)
```

I'm not quite sure how I should grab a two-word tag.

Comment: Why... why wouldn't you choose a single delimiter?

Comment: It comes down to user experience. This is part of my validation process and instead of throwing the user an error, I would like it to just sort of "figure it out" for them, since it can be done.

Comment: Maybe it's just a "power user" thing, but I'd much rather be told that there's a single delimiter I can use, and be told _up front,_ rather than sit there trying to guess what twisted logic the program is using.

Comment: I understand the feeling, which is why I'm going to explicitly tell the user that a certain format is preferred, but I don't want to punish them when I can just as easily fix it.

Comment: If you were to do it with just space and double-quotes, how would you do it?

Comment: Well, could you describe how you would decide whether or not a quote delimits a tag, or is part of a tag? What if it's unmatched?

Comment: The double-quotes would delimit a multi-word tag (where spaces would be kept). The single-word tags would be delimited by spaces.

Comment: Honestly, I wouldn't use a regex.

Comment: Your comments didn't even seem to try to help. Why did you comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not a preg_match_all?

```
preg_match_all('/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)|(?:"([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+)")/i', 'Tag Tag2, Tag3 "Tag" "A Tag"', $result);
```

**Edit:**

I accept the unelegantless part of the solution, however it does not return the double quotes. Here is the code I mentioned before. Please, paste the more elegant one you find :)

```
<?php
preg_match_all('/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)|(?:"([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+)")/i', 'Tag Tag2, Tag3 "Tag" "A Tag"', $result);
$result=array_filter(array_map('array_filter', $result));
print_r(array_merge($result[1], $result[2]));
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Tag
    [1] => Tag2
    [2] => Tag3
    [3] => Tag
    [4] => A Tag
)
```

Comment: This is the output I get when using this: 

    `array (
      0 => 
      array (
        0 => 'Tag',
        1 => 'Tag2',
        2 => 'Tag3',
        3 => '"Tag"',
        4 => '"A Tag"',
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        0 => 'Tag',
        1 => 'Tag2',
        2 => 'Tag3',
        3 => '',
        4 => '',
      ),
      2 => 
      array (
        0 => '',
        1 => '',
        2 => '',
        3 => 'Tag',
        4 => 'A Tag',
      ),
    )`

Comment: I'm not a PHP guy, but merging the second and third array and removing empty values is the result you are looking for, right?

Comment: Seems a little unelegant to me to do that. Not to mention, the regex returns the double quotes, which is not desired. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: You're code is correct, and inelegant working code is better than not-working elegant code. I will post if I find something better. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna give this a try.

```
preg_match_all('/([^"\' ,]+)|(["\'])(\2|[^\2]+?)\2/', $subject, $matches);
$matches = array_map(static function ($v) {return trim($v,'\'"');},$matches[0]);
print_r($matches);
```

It also allows for umlaute and such stuff as well as escaped quotes with quoted blocks.

Comment: The `(\2|[^\2]+?)` part is incorrect. See `'/[^"\' ,]+|(["\']).+?\1/'`.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other answers that `preg_match_all()` is probably better suited because the parsing of the text is not solely determined by a variable delimiting substring. With the right pattern, it is unnecessary to iterate through the matched data and remove unwanted characters. Rather, you want to match substrings that are either:

1. Not enclosed in double quotes and may not contain a comma nor a space (because these are used as delimiters) or
2. Enclosed by double quotes and may not contain double quotes.

My pattern uses `(?| ... )` (branch reset) to ensure that both capture groups store matched text in `[1]`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/4Dl9i))

```
$tagfield = 'Tag Tag2, Tag3 "Tag" "A Tag"';
preg_match_all('~(?|"([^"]+)"|([^ ,]+))~', $tagfield, $m);
var_export($m[1]);
echo "\n";
print_r($m[1]);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'Tag',
  1 => 'Tag2',
  2 => 'Tag3',
  3 => 'Tag',
  4 => 'A Tag',
)
Array
(
    [0] => Tag
    [1] => Tag2
    [2] => Tag3
    [3] => Tag
    [4] => A Tag
)
```

If your input might contain escaped quotes, you can extend the pattern to accommodate that. (this is demonstrated in the above Demo link)

```
$tagfield = 'Tag Tag2, Tag3 "Tag" "A Tag" "with \" escaped \\" quote" "\slash"';

preg_match_all('~(?|"((?:[^\\\\"]+|\\\\.)*)"|([^ ,]+))~', $tagfield, $m);
```

Answer (score -1):

make allowance for space in your preg /[^(.)^a-zA-Z0-9/s]+/ slash s

Comment: I tried your solution and a few mods, but couldn't get it to work.